# Evaluating Indefinite Integrals of the form $\int\frac{f(x)}{p(x) \sqrt{q(x)}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

One learns evaluating indefinite integrals of the form $$ \int \frac{f(x)}{p(x)\sqrt{q(x)}} \ dx $$ where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are linear polynomials.

How to evaluate these integrals if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are quadratic or cubic in nature. Is there any method for evaluating them.

Examples of such integrals are: $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})\sqrt{x^{2}+b^{2}}} \ \mathrm dx$ or $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{(x^{3}+a^{3})\sqrt{x^{3}+b^{3}}} \ \mathrm dx$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $q$ is quadratic, then these can be done by trigonometric/hyperbolic
substiuitions. If $q$ is cubic then they are are elliptic integrals,
not in general expressible in elementary terms, but expressible in terms
of elementary functions and the standard examples of elliptic integrals.

Comment: For Chandru: As a matter of fact, as long as $q$ has degree $\leq 4$, the integral is an elliptic integral; of course, it can happen due to degeneracy that your "elliptic integral" becomes expressible as a logarithm (that may or may not have square roots).

Answer (score 7):

There are algorithms due to Abel, Liouville, Risch, Davenport, Trager et al. for solving the general problem of the **algebraic** (vs. transcendental) case of integration in finite terms (elementary and algebraic functions). Here's an illuminating excerpt from the introduction of [Barry Trager's 1984 MIT Thesis](http://hdl.handle.net/1721.1/15391) (coincidentally Barry was working right next door to me disproving Hardy's statement that no algorithm exists at the same time I was disproving an analogous Hardy statement while inventing algorithms for computing limits / asymptotics - while we were both student members of the MIT Mathlab Group - the research group that developed the Macsyma computer algebra system).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've been meaning to look for a copy of Trager's thesis, so thanks for pointing it out! Too bad it is not a printable version, but I can still use this.

Answer (score 2):

For the quadratic, first put $x = a \tan \theta$ then put $t = \sin \theta$

(First write $p(t)$ in the form $x^2 + a^2$ where $x = t+r$, $a$ could possibly be complex)

Don't know about the cubic.

Comment: Moron: the cubic requires a whole 'nother new set of functions: http://dlmf.nist.gov/19 ; unless of course your cubic has for instance multiple roots.

Comment: @J.Mangaldan: I guessed so! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here i have found one more method for evaluvating integrals of the form $$ I= \frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})\sqrt{x^{2}+b^{2}}} \ dx $$

Let $y = \displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+b^{2}}{x^{2}+a^{2}}}$, then by differentiating one can see that $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(a^{2}-b^{2})x}{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{3/2} (x^{2}+b^{2})^{1/2}}$$

Thus $I$ becomes $$\frac{(x^{2}+a^{2})^{1/2}}{(a^{2}-b^{2})x} \ dy$$

Also $(x^{2}+a^{2})y^{2}=x^{2}+b^{2}$ so that we have $\displaystyle x^{2}= \frac{b^{2}-a^{2}y^{2}}{y^{2}-1}$ and $$x^{2}+a^{2} = \frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{y^{2}-1}$$ So $I$ further reduces to $$ I = \frac{1}{a^{2}-b^{2}} \int \frac{\sqrt{b^{2}-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{b^{2}-a^{2}y^{2}}} \ dy = \frac{1}{a\sqrt{b^{2}-a^{2}}} \cos^{-1}\frac{ay}{b} \ (a < b)$$

For $a>b$ one can rearrange $$I = \frac{1}{a^{2}-b^{2}} \int \frac{\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}{\sqrt{a^{2}y^{2}-b^{2}}} \ dy$$

Comment: @J.M: It should be fine now, i believe. I have altered $y$, where there was a mistake at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Gradshteyn & Rizhik makes a good discussion about that in chapter 2 ( Indefinite Integrals ).

In particular, they discuss an important method: Ostrogradskiy–Hermite.